# Implementing a Traffic Light Checker

Tags: code-challenge, string

A three-color traffic light must switch lights in the following order: red, green, yellow, red.

To indicate when crossing slowly without a stop is permitted, the yellow signal may be flashed. To indicate when crossing immediately after a full stop is permitted, the red signal may be flashed.

Either flash sequence may only be started after the red light is lit and must be followed with a red. All lights are initially off. All sequences must begin a red light. Lighting any light causes all other lights to turn off.  No color may be repeated: e.g., red, red is not allowed.

Task:

Write a program that checks a sequence of light codes and determines if that sequence follows or violates the traffic light rules.

Input
Read from STDIN a sequence of the follow codes:  R (red), Y (yellow), G (Green),  P (Pause - flash red),  C (Caution - flash yellow), and X (off). Each code must be separated with a space.  The entire sequence is submitted by an end-of-line (e.g., pressing the Enter key.)  A sequence must have no more than 15 codes in total.

Winning criteria:

Output
Write to STDOUT an evaluation of the sequence:

ACCEPT     >> The entire input sequence meets all rules.

REJECT     >> The input sequence violates any sequence constraint; for example G Y.

ERROR      >> The input is malformed – undefined code, too short, too long, etc.

```
EXAMPLES:

1 - Input: R G Y R C R G Y R                  Output: ACCEPT  
2 - Input: G Y R G Y R                        Output: REJECT      
3 - Input: R Y G P                            Output: REJECT      
4 - Input: R G Y                              Output: ERROR       
5 - Input: X 8 S                              Output: ERROR       
6 - Input: R G Y R C R P R G Y R G Y R G Y R  Output: ERROR
```

You do not have to worry about the reasons listed below, they are only used a reference as to why the input strings have either been Accepted, Rejected or Erroneous.

Reasons:

1. Correct
2. Doesn’t start with R
3. Invalid sequence
4. Undefined code
5. Undefined Codes e.g. X is not part of the grammar
6. The input is malformed – undefined code, too short, too long, etc.

Comment: Can you please specify a winning criteria? And can you please indicate how the `X` symbol should be handled?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the final item in the sequence? How can a sequence be "too short"?

Comment: There are constraints on the final item of the sequence, it has to be a X(off) or R(Red). A sequence maybe to short however this falls under this situation may fall Undefined Category or Invalid sequence category.

Comment: Seems a bit trivial for `code-challenge`.

Comment: Why is 4 an error and not reject?  Short sequences seem possible, e.g. `R C R`... your stated reason 'undefined code' is wrong.  Also, `X` is part of your grammar, but not a part of your acceptable sequences... what?

Comment: The alleged "winning criteria" isn't. It's an acceptance criteria for working programs that *does not distinguish* one from another. It leave this post looking like you want someone to write a program for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^^ Neat line ardnew, but check yourself for cases

```
1: R G Y R P
2: R G Y C
```

This was one of the questions from the IEEE contest

To determine the next light in the sequence its simply (let c = color of light)

```
(c == 'R') ? ('G', 'P', 'C') : (c == 'G') ? ('Y') : ('R')
```

Those conditions follows from the question statement

- If the light is RED, the next light can only be (GREEN, PAUSE, CAUTION)
- If the light is GREEN, the next light can only be (YELLOW)
- Else (light is (YELLOW, PAUSE, CAUTION)) the next light is RED

The first conditions follow from the fact that its always RED GREEN YELLOW

The flashing lights PAUSE and CAUTION require there be a RED immediately before and after

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 83 chars

good grief, halfway through golfing this thing i realized its a code-*challenge*

```
$_=<>;chop;print/.{30}|[^RYGPCX ]|\S\S/?ERROR:s/^(R (C|P|G Y) )+R?$//?ACCEPT:REJECT
```